# JWindow doesn't appear

Tags: java, swing, layout, look-and-feel

My `JWindow` didn't appear at all when I tried using it with the SeaGlass [Look and Feel](http://seaglass.googlecode.com/svn/doc/usage.html), even though I set it to be visible.

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.*;
import com.seaglasslookandfeel.*;
public class SEAGLASS {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
                        "com.seaglasslookandfeel.SeaGlassLookAndFeel");

                    SEAGLASS demo = new SEAGLASS();
                  } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public SEAGLASS(){
        JWindow window = new JWindow();

        window.setVisible(true); //IT WAS NOT VISIBLE WHEN I RUN IT??//

        window.getRootPane().setWindowDecorationStyle(JRootPane.NONE);
        JButton bu1 = new JButton("MY BUTTON");
        bu1.setBounds(100, 100, 120, 50);
        window.getContentPane().add(bu1);
        window.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. Use layouts, layout padding & borders with `pack()` instead of `null` layouts and `setBounds`.  2) Don't set the layout after components are added. 3) Check these type of things without seaglass before bringing the PLAF into it.  I 'saw' that code fail with the default PLAF.

Answer (score 3):

```
    window.setSize(500,500); // set it to a non 0 size!
```

Comment: @Ak Z and `window.setVisible(true);` must be last code line in the constructor